# Magento XMLRPC API Fails Using finset Operator

Tags: api, magento, xml-rpc

Magento version 1.4.1.1

I'm trying to retrieve a product list filtered for a specific website using the XMLRPC API (catalog_product.list method call). The server returns "unknown error". I can call this same method and filter by status, sku, etc. But anytime I try to filter on a field that can contain multiple values (e.g. websites, categories, category_ids), I get the unknown error.

I'm using C# and Charles Cook's excellent xmlrpc.net library. I've captured the XML being sent to the server as shown below. Can anyone provide any insight into why this is happening?

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>call</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>81a7c4fffec8e78a6fe4b3f15f3e5cd0</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>catalog_product.list</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <array>
          <data>
            <value>
              <struct>
                <member>
                  <name>status</name>
                  <value>
                    <struct>
                      <member>
                        <name>eq</name>
                        <value>
                          <string>1</string>
                        </value>
                      </member>
                    </struct>
                  </value>
                </member>
              </struct>
            </value>
          </data>
        </array>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

This doesn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>call</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>5d7412249845e29458b63e3b03935445</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>catalog_product.list</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <array>
          <data>
            <value>
              <struct>
                <member>
                  <name>websites</name>
                  <value>
                    <struct>
                      <member>
                        <name>finset</name>
                        <value>
                          <string>1</string>
                        </value>
                      </member>
                    </struct>
                  </value>
                </member>
              </struct>
            </value>
          </data>
        </array>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: Looks like it must be an issue with the Magento core API. I have now tested the call using the v2_soap api, and I get the same "unknown error" response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use xdebug and your IDE to step through the request and track down which class is handling it?  You may be able to read the source to track down if the multiple condition operators require a particular syntax.

**EDIT**

I recall that XSLT will not create an array if there is a single node instead of multiple siblings.  So, if `finset` or other multiple condition operators are expecting an array, and you are passing a single node under `<value>`, it's possible that is being received as a scalar and hence the function call is failing?  Perhaps try sending `<value><string>1</string><string>2</string></value>` to test my theory?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give this a try, it may offer more examples as a guide to your problem: 
http://code.google.com/p/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi/

Comment: @BOOMER Thanks for the suggestion. I started using the EZ Newsletter API Nov-2010. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. `code` XmlRpcStruct filterOn = new XmlRpcStruct(); 
XmlRpcStruct filterParams = new XmlRpcStruct(); 
filterParams.Add("finset", new string[] { "melodies" }); //store ID 
filterOn.Add("websites", filterParams); 
Product[] myProducts = Product.List(apiUrl, sessionId, new object[] { filterOn });
`code` Results in `code` Server returned a fault exception: [0] Unknown Error `code`

Comment: I know its redundant but have to ask is the SOAP and SimpleXML PHP Modules installed and working properly? http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento and http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements